# VBA Text File Input/Output function convert to VBS

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a function that works well in VBA but apparently not in VBS.

I believe I have to convert it to use FSO?
But I don't really know how to get started doing that.

It also doesn't seem to like me specifying the argument and function data types?

My function is:

```
Function CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor(ByVal InputFile As String, ByVal OutputFile As String) As Boolean
   CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor = False 'set as failed until the end
   On Error GoTo error1 'error trapping
   Dim ThisString As String, vArray As Variant 'set up the variables

   Open InputFile For Input As #1   'open the input file
   Open OutputFile For Output As #2 'open/create the output file
   Line Input #1, ThisString 'copy the first row (headings)
   Print #2, ThisString

   While Not EOF(1) 'loop for each row
        Line Input #1, ThisString 'read in the row
        vArray = Split(ThisString, ",") 'split into an array

        For x = 0 To UBound(vArray) 'for each field in the array
            If Mid(vArray(x), 3, 1) = "/" And Mid(vArray(x), 6, 1) = "/" Then 'if it is a date (ISDATE doesnt work as they are American!)
              vArray(x) = Mid(vArray(x), 4, 2) & "/" & Left(vArray(x), 2) & "/" & Right(vArray(x), 2) 'switch the day and month around
            End If
        Next x

        Print #2, Join(vArray, ",") 'join array back into comma delim text and put the row into the output file
   Wend

   Close #1 'close the input file
   Close #2 'close the output file
   CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor = True 'success!
   Exit Function 'end

error1:
   'the function will return as false
   On Error Resume Next 'ignore any further errors
   Close #1 'close the input file, if possible
   Close #2 'close the output file, if possible
End Function
```

Comment: Ok I did figure it out, but apparently I am not able to answer my own question yet. I will post my final code tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured it out after lots of trial and error.
It turns out there are lots of things that needed to be different for VBS.

Here is my final code in case it is of use to anyone else:

```
Function CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor(InputFile,OutputFile)
CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor = False 'set as failed until the end

'setup variables etc
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim ThisString , vArray , f1 , f2, fso 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'open and create text files
Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(InputFile, ForReading, True)
Set f2 = fso.CreateTextFile(OutputFile)

'loop for each row
   While f1.AtEndOfStream <> True
        ThisString = f1.Readline        'read in the row
        vArray = Split(ThisString, ",") 'split into an array

        For x = 0 To UBound(vArray) 'for each field in the array
            If Mid(vArray(x), 3, 1) = "/" And Mid(vArray(x), 6, 1) = "/" Then 'if it is a date
              vArray(x) = Mid(vArray(x), 4, 2) & "/" & Left(vArray(x), 2) & "/" & Right(vArray(x), 2) 'switch the day and month around
            End If
        Next 

        f2.WriteLine Join(vArray, ",")  'join array back into comma delim text and put the row into the output file
   Wend

'finish up
f1.Close 'close the input file
f2.Close 'close the output file
Set f1 = Nothing
Set f2 = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

CSV_1304_USA_date_convertor = True 'success!

End Function
```